# Auto Refresh Div Content Using jQuery and AJAX passing variables

Tags: forms, variables, jquery

I am trying to setup a page where the users can select 1 criteria from a select menu and then select the second from another.

I would then like these variables to pass through my auto updating div using ajax so that they are used in the .php that is refreshed.

The select menu is working fine but how would I pass the values through ajax and then make sure it remembered them for the refresh.

**FORM**

```
<select id="employee_user"> 
<option value="">--</option> 
<option value="333">Test User</option> 
<option value="111">Testing Testing</option>     
</select> 

<select id="they" onchange="showUser(this.value, employee_user.value)"> 
<option value="">--</option> 
<option value="20120801" class="333" title="Test User">20120801</option> 
<option value="20110801" class="333" title="Test User">20110801</option> 
<option value="20100801" class="333" title="Test User">20100801</option> 
<option value="20120801" class="111" title="Testing Testing">20120801</option> 
<option value="20110801" class="111" title="Testing Testing">20110801</option> 
</select> 

</form>
```

**AUTO REFRESHING DIV**

```
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#updatingdiv').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#updatingdiv').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#updatingdiv').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#updatingdiv");
        $container.load("getholidaylog.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('getholidaylog.php');
        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

    <div id="updatingdiv"></div>
    <img src="loading.gif" id="loading" alt="loading" style="display:none;" />
```

**and then getholidaylog.php would:**

```
$year = $_GET["year"];
$username = $_GET["username"];
```

and use for the database query.

**EDIT**

```
$j(document).ready(function() {     
    $j("#year_select").change(function (){
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#updatingdiv').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#updatingdiv').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#updatingdiv').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#updatingdiv");

        var user_select= $j('#user_select').val();
        var year_select= $j('#year_select').val();
        $container.load('getholidaylog.php',{username:user_select,year:year_select}); 
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('getholidaylog.php');
        }, 9000);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code passing the values to php page successfully

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#they").change(function () {
        var firstVal = $("#employee_user").val();
        var secVal = $("#they").val();

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "year="+ firstVal +"&username="+ secVal,
                url: "getholidaylog.php",
                success: function(msg){
                $("#updatingdiv").html(msg);

                }
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

but instead of loading the getholidaylog.php into div load the content of respective page into the div

Answer (score 1):

DO Something like this..

Add two hidden fields in your html like this:

```
-------
<input type="hidden" id="userselect" />
<input type="hidden" id="yearselect" />
</form>
```

Now Change your jQuery code like this..

Modify your onchange function of year_select like this and put it separately . Dont include ajax setup in this.

```
            $j("#year_select").change(function (){                   
                $('#userselect').val($('#employee_user').val());
                $('#yearselect').val($('#they').val());
            });
```

Now take the value from hidden field.change these lines.

```
        var user_select= $j('#userselect').val();
        var year_select= $j('#yearselect').val();
```

So your Final hmtl markup would look like this:

```
<select id="employee_user"> 
<option value="">--</option> 
<option value="333">Test User</option> 
<option value="111">Testing Testing</option>     
</select> 

<select id="they" onchange="showUser(this.value, employee_user.value)"> 
<option value="">--</option> 
<option value="20120801" class="333" title="Test User">20120801</option> 
<option value="20110801" class="333" title="Test User">20110801</option> 
<option value="20100801" class="333" title="Test User">20100801</option> 
<option value="20120801" class="111" title="Testing Testing">20120801</option> 
<option value="20110801" class="111" title="Testing Testing">20110801</option> 
</select> 
<select id="employee_user"> 
<option value="">--</option> 
<option value="333">Test User</option> 
<option value="111">Testing Testing</option>     
</select> 

<select id="they" onchange="showUser(this.value, employee_user.value)"> 
<option value="">--</option> 
<option value="20120801" class="333" title="Test User">20120801</option> 
<option value="20110801" class="333" title="Test User">20110801</option> 
<option value="20100801" class="333" title="Test User">20100801</option> 
<option value="20120801" class="111" title="Testing Testing">20120801</option> 
<option value="20110801" class="111" title="Testing Testing">20110801</option> 
</select> 
 <input type="hidden" id="userselect" />
<input type="hidden" id="yearselect" />
</form>
```

and your code will look like this:

```
$(function(){
      $("#year_select").change(function (){                   
                    $('#userselect').val($('#employee_user').val());
                    $('#yearselect').val($('#they').val());
                });

    $.ajaxSetup(
    {
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#updatingdiv').hide();
            $('#loading').show();
        var user_select= $j('#userselect').val();
        var year_select= $j('#yearselect').val();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#updatingdiv').show();
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#updatingdiv').show();
        }
    });

    $container.load('getholidaylog.php',{username:user_select,year:year_select}); 
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $container.load('getholidaylog.php');
    }, 9000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The low level `$.ajax()` method contains a variable called `data` through which you can pass data to the server. So if you want the send data in this case, you can do something like:

```
$.ajax({
  data: {year:1999,username:'Codded'}
});
```

Same goes for `load`, the second parameter there is for passing data, so you can do

```
$("#divId").load('foo.php',{username:'Codded',year:1999});
```

Comment: You forgot to send the data in the Ajax call inside the `setInterval` method.

Comment: oops, ok added that but still not working. Nothing happens when i change the second select

Answer (score 0):

u can use the data attribute of the ajax function to pass the selected value like this example :

```
$.ajax({
data: {'name': 'Dan'} // name is the name of the variable and Dan is the value in your case if the selected value 
});
```

Comment: I have edited my question, how would I include your method into that

Answer (score 0):

Check out your id of select is same as given below because it does not matches with the select box you have coded

```
var user_select= $j('#user_select').val();
var year_select= $j('#year_select').val();
```